# Microsoft Analysis services takes too much time

Tags: sql-server, cubes, azure-analysis-services

I'm using microsoft analysis services to instantiate a cube from SQL server. When launching the profiler, The cube takes around 15 minutes to execute a select from my database. However, when I execute the same query from sql server it only take 1min30s. Meaning that MAS is roughly 8 times slower than sql server. Is that normal ? isn't it a configuration problem ?

Comment: You use materialized cube right? It probably needs some times to materialize the data on your hard drive ;)

Comment: @VeselinDavidov thank you for your answer, I'm using SASS cubes. What do you mean by writing data on hard drive, do you think that will take *9 more time ?

Comment: When processing the cube it stores the actual data in the file system in some optimized data structure and then when you query the cube it doesn't query the database (that's MOLAP cube). So building that cube takes longer than just querying the database.

Comment: Can you include the SQL query and MDX or DAX query you are comparing?

Comment: Is the cube MOLAP or ROLAP?